# How to display a field on a tree view by using xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

[image: Caption for tree view]I have been trying to replace a field in a tree view of another class by using xpath.

```
<xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/group/field/tree/field[@name='test']" position="replace">
<field name="parts_id2" style="width:30%%" attrs="{'invisible':[('sts','not in',['release'])]}"/>
</xpath>
```

But the field does not appear on the tree view, instead it appears sometimes out of the tree somewhere else.

Comment: can u explain in detail .. Why use style="width:30%%" it's not good

Comment: The drop down box many2one appears somewhere else out of the tree sometimes, sometimes it appears in the tree view line

Comment: hi use this last time //sheet//notebook//tree//field[@name="test"]

Answer (score 0):

try this code

[link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account_asset/account_asset_invoice_view.xml#L22)

```
    <xpath expr='//field[@name="ids name"]/tree//field[@name="test"]' position="replace">
          <field name="parts_id2" style="width:30%%" attrs="{'invisible':[('sts','not in',['release'])]}"/>
    </xpath>

expr='//field[@name="parts_lines"]/tree//field[@name="test"]'
```

## or

```
<xpath expr='//field[@name="parts_lines"]/tree//field[@name="test"]' position="attributes">
          <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
 </xpath>
 <xpath expr='//field[@name="parts_lines"]/tree//field[@name="test"]' position="replace">
          <field name="parts_id2" style="width:30%%" attrs="{'invisible':[('sts','not in',['release'])]}"/>
 </xpath>
```

## or

```
//sheet//notebook//tree//field[@name="test"]
```

Comment: what is that ids name? id of the tree view ?

Comment: tree view parent fields name

Comment: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account_analytic_plans/account_analytic_plans_view.xml#L23  check this line of code

Comment: user00000341 first of all thank you, but at random times it occurs out of the tree view itself

Comment: tyr it expr='//field[@name="parts_lines"]/tree//field[@name="test"]' its working on my side i hope work for u tyr it

Comment: it does not work on my side . anyways thanks user00000341

Comment: use this http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output                                               http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester